# Best way to schedule a task to run in next iteration of a Twisted reactor loop

Tags: python, twisted

I want to schedule a task to run in the next iteration of the reactor loop. What's the best way to do it?

reactor.callLater(0, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct:

```
reactor.callLater(0, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorThreads.callFromThread.html), the correct way seems to be as you said, `reactor.callLater(0, ...)`.